# When should I use an MARL approach instead of training one agent while keep the others fixed?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, multi-agent-rl

I have built a custom multi-agent environment with [PettingZoo](https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo), where a turn-based game with two agents, A and B, is setup.

I want to examine situations where malicious behavior may arise, given the game rules, and I am looking into training approaches.

To do that, I have implemented a deterministic policy as a baseline / control.

Fixing agent A to that baseline policy, I want to subsequently train agent B and observe the resulting behaviors.

After B arrives at a desirable behavioral pattern, I want to train agent A to see how it responds to B's actions.

Having the above setting in mind:

- Is the above training approach, which keeps one agent fixed and trains the other, correct?

  Should I follow a MARL approach for training instead, or is the above approach that encapsulates one agent as part of the environment sound?

In general, what are requirements / desiderata to look for that hint that a MARL approach is the correct way and/or a separate training scheme is erroneous?

Comment: I've tried to rewrite the title to summarize your question/problem. Make sure that's correct!!